# How to store strings from a text file in C wihout identical references?

Tags: c, string, pointers, text-files, c-strings

I have a text file and a way to read a word from the text file. This word is stored in a char array and then shipped off to a function to be stored in a node of a tree. Afterwards, the word is reset and the process starts over. However, when I check the tree, all nodes are referring to the same string.

Get word:

```
  node* run(node* root)
   {
       char c;
       int index = 0;
       char word[100];
       fp = fopen("text.txt","rt");
       do
       {
           c = (char)fgetc(fp);
           if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\0' || c == '\t' || c == ',' || c == ';' || c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!' || c == ':')
           {
               root = insert(root, word);
               word[0] = 0;
               index = 0;
           }
           else
           {
               word[index++] = c;
               word[index] = 0;
           }
       }while(c != EOF);

       fclose(fp);
       return root;
   }
```

Do something with the word in insert:

```
node* insert(node* N, char* key)
{
    /* 1.  Perform the normal BST rotation */
    if (N == NULL)
        return(newNode(key));
   ...
}
```

Make a new node from the string:

```
node* newNode(char* string)
{
    node* newNode = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->data = string;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->height = 1;  //Height of a leaf is one
    return(newNode);
}
```

However, after I add the newNode and reset my word, the value of data in root changes to whatever the original word changes to... I am guessing something odd is going on with pointers? Essentially, how do I assign newNode->data to the the value of string AT THE CURRENT MOMENT instead of its value for all eternity.

Comment: BTW: Better to use `int c; ... c = fgetc(fp); if (c == EOF || c == ' ' || c == '\n' ...)`.  Present code is mapping `EOF` into 1 of the `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are using `word` in creating every node, which just stores the address of the first character from `word`.

Change

```
newNode->data = string;
```

to

```
newNode->data = strdup(string);
```

Answer (score -1):

What I think is happening is that you create a pointer at the beginning of your run method. You only allocate memory once. And then all your nodes point to the exact same place in memory. Whenever you change the string stored at that pointer, it will change for all nodes.

```
// Allocation of memory only once
char word[100];
```

You need to do a new allocation when you assign the string to your nodes and copy your string.
Something like this:

```
char copy[100];
strcopy(copy, word);
insert(root, word);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: But instead of a single `word` you only shift the problem to having only one `copy`. So not a solution.